# Running Ajax/NodeJS with JetBrains

Tags: pycharm, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I am developing an Angular application that renders data received through an ajax request to a NodeJS application. Both the Angular app and the NodeJS app are in the same project.

Is there a way I can configure WebStorm so that when I kick off the page using JavaScript Debug configuration, it also starts the NodeJS applicatoin on the same port?

Basically, how can I launch an Angular page with Ajax and a NodeJS app under the same run configuration in WebStorm or PyCharm?

Comment: Every Run/Debug Configuration has "Before launch" section where you can specify another Run Configuration to be launched before running this one (P.S. they launched asynchronously so it may happen that main config will be ready sooner than the one launched in "before" section)

Comment: This will start two processes on two different ports.  My question was about running them on the same port (because I can always just kick off node manually outside of PyCharm -- that's not the issue).

Answer (score 0):

When you configure node run script there is second tab called `Browser/Live Edit` and it's run after node script is executed. As you can see on screenshot you can specify browser, to run it with or without javascript debugger

[image]

Comment: As far as I can tell the Node app and the Live Edit page are still being served from different ports (different server instances), which breaks the Same Origin Policy when making Ajax requests.

Comment: I've put the `localhost:3000` as an example, you of course have to use your own, and if that causes the CORS issues then it's a different problem to solve

Comment: Yes, there are two processes running (PyCharm kicked off two separate run configurations): one for node on port 8888 and another for Live Edit on port 63342.

Comment: Did you specified a static file in this dialog above?

Comment: I found PyCharm documentation that confirms what I'm seeing.  I also found how to [deal with CORS](https://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/help/using-jetbrains-chrome-extension.html).  This helps, but the whole thing feels like a huge crutch because now I have to deal with Ajax URLs being different between dev and prod.